# Magento 2: Rest API "Checkout Cart Product Add After" event is not working

Tags: event-observer, addtocart, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I have faced issue in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event using `add to cart rest API`.

Same add to cart event is working in website. But it is not working in Add to cart rest API.

**Add to cart API URL:** http://magento2/rest/V1/carts/mine/items

**Method:** POST

Below is my event file path:

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice_subscrption_product_add" instance="Vendor\CustomModule\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Observer/CustomPrice.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "Calling observer.....";die;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any have idea about to call add to cart event in rest API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to add events.xml inside /etc/events.xml and check once

Comment: @Jack I have tried with to placed `event.xml` in the etc directory but not working. `/etc/events.xml`

Comment: any clue in a log file?

Comment: No any log related to API.

Comment: are you trying with fresh Magento or customized Magento project?

Comment: Yes. I have tried with fresh Magento.

Comment: Any solution on the this?

Comment: @Devidas No solution for same.

Comment: I have one question. When I create order using rest API then event will be execut or not ?

Comment: @KirtiNariya Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of events you can match during 'magento add_product rest api'

sales_quote_item_set_product
sales_quote_item_qty_set_after
sales_quote_product_add_after
sales_quote_item_save_before
sales_quote_item_save_after

"sales_quote_add_item" works only on add product, it doesn't work on update qty